# MEW wallet to wallet transfer not arrived

Tags: ether, pending-transactions

I have sent ETH from one my ether wallets to another; this is the TX: 0xfd1f16c53057a5c8bca535d088b3976068869bdc676d45a47d324cd6a7b24dfe at Etherscan where the status reports 'success'however my balance still shows zero.
Can someone please advise what i need to do?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How do you check the balance? Your local blockchain is probably not synchronized and it is the reason the balance is outdated.
Etherscan reports that balance is not zero.

https://etherscan.io/address/0x1e37227db9cc12c44f69a9d32def4a9c0c85ad5c

Comment: Hi Andrey,
I checked my balance at Ethersan, while I was waiting for a response to my question, I refreshed my wallets - the transfer was confirmed. All is well.
Best 
Rupert